# how to check values of multiple drop down list using jquery

Tags: jquery, forms

I wanted to check whether B,A,C are selected from the three deop down list using Jquery
my HTML Lists

```
<select id="option1">
                        <option value="none" selected>--Select--</option>
                        <option value="A">a</option>
                        <option value="B">b</option>
                        <option value="C">c</option>

                    </select>
                </div>
                <div  class="wrapper">
                <span>b.Features are</span>
                    <select id="option2">
                        <option value="none" selected>--Select--</option>
                        <option value="A">a</option>
                        <option value="B">b</option>
                        <option value="C">c</option>

                    </select>
                </div>
                <div  class="wrapper">
                <span>c.Data binding</span>
                    <select id="option3">
                        <option value="none" selected>--Select--</option>
                        <option value="A">a</option>
                        <option value="B">b</option>
                        <option value="C">c</option>

                    </select>
                </div>
```

I tried this using Javascript but i need to implement using Jquery

```
  var atp = document.getElementById( "ID" );
 if(atp.option1.value !== "B" || atp.option2.value !=="C" || atp.option3.value !=="A")
   {
   //do something
   }
```

how to implement this using jquery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the jQuery Funktion val(). 
http://api.jquery.com/val/

```
 if($('#option1').val() !== "B" || $('#option2').val() !=="C" || $('#option3').val() !=="A")
   {
   //do something
   }
```

Comment: this is showing some error..instead of value, its working fine with val()

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$.each` :

```
$("select").each(function() {
    if (this.value == "A" || ..) { //obviously do all the checking
        //found a select matching the conditions
        //Do stuff!
        return true; //this exits the each loop ^^
    }
});
```

Comment: I found this helpful when I wanted to check multiple drop downs for a single value - i.e. do any have the value "N". However the code should be `if ($(this).value etc..`

Comment: @TobyBeresford - The code should *not* be `$(this).value` - `.value` isn't a property on a jQuery object. The above answer is correct.

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick:

```
   if($('#option1').val() == "B" && $('#option2').val() =="A" && $('#option3').val() =="C")
       {
       //all values selected
       }else{
       //false
    }
```